# Moving files from 1 directory to other

Tags: shell, unix

I want to move files from 1 directory to another in UNIX.

I have file names in a string like *"File 1.txt, File 2.txt"*

So I want to extract these file names from the string and then archive those to another folder.

I tried something like this but was not able to implement the entire solution -

```
echo "Open Incidents 08-02-2021.csv,Closed Incidents 08-02-2021.csv"  | tr "," "\n" | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/ $//'
```

Output - "Open Incidents 08-02-2021.csv" "Closed Incidents 08-02-2021.csv"

With this syntax, as you can see the output, i was able to enclose quotes around the file names as there are spaces in the file name and a space between the names, but was not sure, how to pass these to the mv command now to get the files moved to another folder.

I know we can do this in For loops, but was hoping for a solution without that.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think `xargs` can solve you issue:

```
echo "Open Incidents 08-02-2021.csv,Closed Incidents 08-02-2021.csv"|tr "," "\n"|sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/ $//'|xargs -I mv {} <other_dir>/
```

`{}` will hold the output of previous command and pass that to `mv` command .

Comment: It gives error after adding xargs. `Closed Incidents 08-02-2021.csv is not a directory`

Comment: This works... `echo "Open Incidents 08-02-2021.csv,Closed Incidents 08-02-2021.csv" | tr "," "\n" | xargs -I {} mv {} <folder>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using awk and a while loop:

```
while read line;
do 
   echo "mv $line /path/to/newdir";
   # mv "$line" "/path/to/newdir";
done <<< "$(awk 'BEGIN { RS="," } { print $0 }' <<< "Open Incidents 08-02-2021.csv,Closed Incidents 08-02-2021.csv")" # Use awk to set the record separator to "," and print each record on a separate line
```

Verify the echo of the move command before removing the comment tag and executing